# Microsoft Excel: Formula that generates String Content, and Double Quotes

Tags: excel-formula

Microsoft Excel: Formula that generates String Content, and Double Quotes

I generate the contents of a batch file in a Microsoft Excel.  Then I copy commands to a .BAT file and run the .BAT file.

With each row in the Excel file, I generate a set of BATCH commands, which are currently separated by "&" ... perfectly valid.  For example,

The formula:

```
="@ECHO OFF&cd \users\imemine\&"&"""C:\Program Files (x86)\program\program.exe"" -parameter1 -parameter2 """&A1&""""&"&echo.message"
```

Output:

```
@ECHO OFF&cd \users\imemine\&"C:\Program Files (x86)\program\program.exe" -parameter - parameter2 "string"&echo.message
```

Just for aesthetic reasons, I'd like to replace the "&" with a newline character and have each BATCH command in its own line.

So, I tried to replace the "&" my Excel formula with char(10).  I also tried the Alt-Enter character in the formula.

But the output I get has unnecessary double quote characters.  For example:

```
"@ECHO OFF&
cd \users\imemine\&""C:\Program Files (x86)\program\program.exe"" -parameter -parameter2 ""string""&echo.message"
```

What do I do?

I'd like something like this when I copy the Excel formula result into the BATCH file:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd \users\imemine\
"C:\Program Files (x86)\program\program.exe" -parameter - parameter2 "string"
echo.message
```

Thank you, Joanna

Comment: You have packaged your entire `.bat` file in a single string in a single cell.  Why not use sequential cells in a column ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible with formulas. We can use as workaround a rectangle shape + [a piece of macro](mandatory, but copy from shape is tedious)

1.Use SUBSTITUTE to replace "&" in your command line.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B4,"&",CHAR(10))
```

2.Create a rectangle shape and link it with the cell containing the new command line.
(select the shape then paste this in the formula bar)

```
=$B$7
```

3.Insert the macro. Microsoft Forms 2.0 activated.

```
Sub ShapeCb()
Dim obj As New DataObject
Dim strText As String
strText = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text
obj.SetText strText
obj.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Sheet :
[image: cmd]

Output once copy-pasted:
[image: Output]